# Correct bias with known DAG

Tags: multiple-regression, causality, unbiased-estimator

I have the following causal graph:

$T \to P$

$(T, P) \to S$

So $T$ causes $P$ (partially) and $T$ and $P$ both cause $S.$ If I just regress $S\,\text{~}\,T + P,$ I will get an overestimated effect for $P$ and an underestimated effect for $T.$ I thought to correct this by regressing $P\,\text{~}\,T$ and then generating a residual $P^* = P - bT$ which makes $P$ net of $T$ ($b$ is the coefficient).

I then regress $S\,\text{~}\,T + P^*$ and I get a better estimate of $T.$ But I think $P^*$ might still be biased.

Maybe I should run a bivariate model where $(S, P)\,\text{~}\,((P T), (0 T)) + \Sigma$ where $\Sigma$ is a covariance matrix.

What do you advise?

Comment: Which variable is your base cause, and which variable is your base effect? That is, you want to know the causal effect of which variable on which variable?

Comment: If you are interested in the causal effect of $T$ on $S,$ then the correct regression is $S\,\text{~}\,T.$ Some of the causal effect will be mediated through $P,$ but that's fine. It would be INCORRECT to include $P$ in your regression. If you are interested in the causal effect of $P$ on $S,$ then $T$ is a confounding variable, and you must regress $S\,\text{~}\,T+P$ to condition on $T.$

Comment: I am interested in the unbiased estimates of T and P upon S. So I am interested in both causes.

Comment: My second comment is your answer.